# Why is $P(A \mid C \cap B) = P(A \mid C)$ true in this instance?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, conditional-expectation

As I was reading through this paper http://www.jstor.org/stable/25652278 I came across the following problem:

Consider an urn with $N$ colored balls, the number of red balls, $X$, has a binomial distribution $X \sim B(N,p)$ with $p$ known. We independently and randomly draw two balls from the urn with replacement, that is, we draw a ball, note its color, then put it back, draw a second ball then also note its color. Now let $F_1$ be the event that the first ball is red and let $F_2$ be the event that the second ball is red. While it is clear that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are independent, the paper claims that they are also independent when conditioning on $\{X=n\}$, i.e. the paper claims that $P(F_2|X=n \cap F_1)=P(F_2|X=n)$. However, it is not true in general that $P(A|C \cap B)=P(A|C)$ when $A$ and $B$ are independent, [see my previous question for a counterexample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630951/given-any-events-a-b-and-c-where-a-and-b-are-independent-is-it-true-t).

My question here is why $P(A|C \cap B)=P(A|C)$ is true in this problem (where $A, B$ and $C$ correspond to $F_2, F_1$ and $\{X=n\}$ respectively) but not in general? what extra assumptions did the paper utilize to arrive at this result?

Comment: To verify that $P(F_2 | \{X = n\}, F_1) = P(F_2|X = n)$, using the condition that the sampling is with replacement, so both probabilities are equal to $\frac{n}{N}I_{\{1, 2, \ldots, N\}}(n)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the statement "while it is clear that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are independent" is wrong -- in fact they are conditionally independent given $X = n$ but not unconditionally independent.  I can see you still have some difficulty in telling conditional independence and unconditional independence apart.  Take more time to expose yourself to more concrete examples.

Comment: I see, after pondering about it, I do now realize the draws are not independent when the number of red balls is not known. Thank you for your help @Zhanxiong